# Mesibo on-premise startup message On-Premise is not enabled

Tags: mesibo

I have mesibo on-premise server running. But it displays below error in docker logs.

.------------------------------[ System Message ]------------------------------.
|                                                                              |
| On-Premise is not enabled - login to Mesibo console to enable it             |
|______________________________________________________________________________|

I have already enabled On-Premise option on mesibo web console after starting of server.
Now I'm not even able to logged into mesibo web console which says check your Internet connection.

Comment: the console was down for 15 minutes for an upgrade, you should be able to log in now.

Comment: Ok, Thanks Marks for confirmation. yes seems we had faced this error for every login. Now working fine.